# pip install -r requirements.txt doesn't expand my environment variables

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, requirements.txt

I have private package in a Gitlab registry. In order to install it I had to create a token.

When I  run the following command:

```
pip install my-package-name --index-url https://${GITLAB_TOKEN_USER}:${GITLAB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/packages/pypi/simple
```

The package get installed properly. With following lines (we can see that the ENV var where expanded properly)

```
Looking in indexes: https://gitlab%2Bdeploy-token-564332:****@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234567/packages/pypi/simple
Collecting my-package-name.
  Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/packages/ ...
....
```

But when i try to install through `pip install -r requirements.txt`. I get this message:

```
Looking in indexes: https://%24%7BGITLAB_TOKEN_USER%7D:****@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234567/packages/pypi/simple
WARNING: 401 Error, Credentials not correct for https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234567/packages/pypi/simple/my-package-name/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-package-name (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for my-package-name
```

And it seems that when I use this command the ENV var doesn't get expanded.

My `requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
--index-url https://${GITLAB_TOKEN_USER}:${GITLAB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234567/packages/pypi/simple

my-package-name
```

**I'm using pip version 22.3.1**

Any why this is happenning ? And if there is any other way to install multiple private packages without hardcoding my token in the requirements.

Comment: What version of pip are you using? Run `pip --version` to check.

Comment: Does pip _document_ that it allows variables to be used in these places? I wouldn't expect it to otherwise.

Comment: I've added the information to my question; i'm using pip 22.3.1

Comment: Note that if you tell pip to check your code out from gitlab using git (whether over SSH or otherwise), all of git's dotfile-based configuration options (and things like SSH agents, if using ssh as your transport) come into play, so you have a lot more ways to authenticate without hardcoding credentials.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#using-environment-variables I read that on the documentation

Comment: I went ahead and looked at the [code](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1463081f10de6bfad81afe0d68272e7c3bedbadf/src/pip/_internal/req/req_file.py#L495-L519) pip is using for expanding environment variables, only reason it wouldn't expand in your case would be you actually don't have that environment variable set or it is an empty string.

Comment: Yes my bad; I thought that using `source .env`would define my ENV var but they were considered shell var. Using `export MY_ENV=value` solved the problem

Comment: Run `set -a` to make all variables be automatically exported before the `source` command, then `set +a` to turn that back off.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Abdul Aziz Barkat my environment variable were not set.

I used `source .env` to load my variables. And when I was checking with `echo $MY_ENV` my var were displaying. So I though it was ok.

But when I used `cat <(envsubst < requirements.txt)` to check for my variables. They were replaced in my requirements.txt by an empty string.

As pointed by @Charles Duffy, in order to export my var from my `.env` file I should use:

```
set -a
source .env
set +a
```

this source helped me: https://ostechnix.com/difference-between-defining-bash-variables-with-and-without-export/

Comment: I wasn't running "export" but after looking at your link it points me in the right direction and then requirements.txt was able to expand my variable finally

So for the initial question, you should be looking at avoid "GITLAB_TOKEN_USER=xxx" and look forward to run it like "export GITLAB_TOKEN_USER=xxx" on your ".bashrc" or ".zprofile" for MAC, and off course reload the console to re-run the "pip install" again and the expansion will work now